# JqGrid is getting displayed as a non editable modal inside a jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jqgrid, jquery-dialog

I am using the jquery dialog and displaying JqGrid inside the jquery dialog box. Everything is working perfectly fine, But the JqGrid is getting displayed as a non editable modal. So i couldn edit anything inside the dialog box.

Even if i close and reopen the dialog box it remains the same, only if i refresh the page it becomes normal until that the whole dialog box is displaying as a non editable modal...

The code logic works well and good.. It seems to be an UI issue.. Kindly help me out..Anyhow I am posting my code below for your reference..kindly view that and help me in resolving the issue..

This is my aspx code:

```
<div>
<span id="span_create" style="color: #88b807; margin-left: 839px;
                            margin-top: -12px; cursor: pointer; display: block">Create</span>
</div>
     <div id="Createdialog" style="display: none; overflow: hidden">
                    <table id="table" style="border-spacing: 7px 7px; margin-left: 5px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="SubHeading" style="font-size: 10pt;">Private Space Name </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_spacename" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span class="SubHeading" style="font-size: 10pt;">Users </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_users" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btn_addusers" Text="Add" Style="margin-left: 0px;" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <table id="users_grid">
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <input type="button" id="Btn_Submit" value="Create" style="margin-left: 280px; margin-top: 8px;"
                        runat="server" />
                </div>
```

This is my Js code:

```
$("#Createdialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Create Private space',
                modal: true,
                position: 'center',
                width: 900

            });

            $('#span_create').click(function() {
                $("#Createdialog").find('input:text, textarea').val('');
                $('#Createdialog').dialog('open');
                return false;
            });

$('#btn_addusers').click(function() {

        $("#users_grid").jqGrid({

            colNames: ['User_ID', 'Name', 'Email_Id'],
            colModel: [{ name: 'User_ID', index: 'User ID', width: 130, editable: false, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 350, editable: false, sortable: false },
            { name: 'Email_Id', index: 'Email Id', width: 350, editable: false, sortable: false}],

            width: 400,
            height: 'auto',
            multiselect: true,
            modal: false

        });


        var UserID = $('#Header1_txt_users').val();
        var datapost = {};


        datapost.UserId = UserID;
        var postJSONData = JSON.stringify({ 'postdata': JSON.stringify(datapost) });


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: postJSONData,
            url: 'PrivateSpaceService.asmx/GetUserDetails',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function success(response) {

                UserArr = response.d;

            },
            error: function failure(response) {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });

        var mydata;


        for (var i = 0; i < UserArr.length; i++) {


            mydata = {};


            mydata.User_ID = UserArr[i].UserId;
            mydata.Name = UserArr[i].UserName;
            mydata.Email_Id = UserArr[i].EmailId;

            $("#users_grid").jqGrid('addRowData', 'GridData_Row_' + (i + 1), mydata);


        }
        return false;


    });
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's very difficult to understand what problem you have. You wrote for example "But the JqGrid is getting displayed as a non editable modal". You use `editable: false` property in every columns. Which editing you what to have? Which "editable modal" you mean? Moreover you fill the grid body in very ineffective way by usage of `addRowData`. If you need to fill grid with data loaded per Ajax from the server you should use jqGrid directly and use just some jqGrid options like `jsonReader` which corresponds the format of data returned from the server.

Comment: @Oleg Once i click the "btn_addusers" inside the jquery dialog the jqgrid will be displayed.. But it is displaying as an modal inside the dialog box (i.e) as if a modal dialog box in a page...

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. jqGrid is just a visual element on the dialog which you create. How it can be "modal"? I still not understand what kind of editing you mean.

Comment: @Oleg If a dialog opens in a page..It will form a modal and we cant be able to edit anything in the page.. Similar thing happens in my  case.. I have a dialog box and i m displaying the jqgrid inside it.. But the jqgrid is getting displayed in the same way as i said above so that i couldn edit anything in the dialog box.. I dont want to edit anything in jqgrid.. I just want to edit some textbox values in  the Dialog box..

Comment: @Oleg when i checked in Firebug it loading a class [class="ui-widget-overlay jqgrid-overlay"] when the Jqgrid is displayed.. Think this is causing the issue

Comment: @Oleg I got my solution http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/basic-example-overlay-stuck-after-load/

Answer (score 0):

May be z-index is the problem. Here is an exemple (http://jsfiddle.net/c3BPP/ ) of sample code with a bigger z-index and it works. with z-Index like 100 its non-editable

Try It.

Comment: Dialog works fine for me.. Only after the JQgrid is displayed I am facing the issue